# Git checkout <branch> No funciona!

Tags: git

Este es el problema cuando veo las ramas del repositorio aparece estas que son remotas

```html
Hunter:albanova hunterx$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/api
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/web
Hunter:albanova hunterx$
```

Después quiero entrar a la rama "web" con `git checkout web` pero no cambia a la rama.

```html
Hunter:albanova hunterx$ git checkout web
Hunter:albanova hunterx$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/api
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/web
Hunter:albanova hunterx$
```

Ya intente hacer `git fetch --all` pero no se como resolver esto de las ramas "remotes".

Answer (score 1):

1. Tienes que darle a conocer a git los contenidos del repositorio remoto
2. Una vez git tiene conocimiento sobre los contenidos del repositorio remoto puedes hacer checkout a cualquier rama remota

---

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b web origin/web
```